# Updating react-table values after Dragging and Dropping a row in React Redux

Tags: react-redux

I´ve accomplished the react drag and drop functionality into my project so i can reorder a row in a react table´s list. The problem is i have a column named 'Sequence', witch shows me the order of the elements, that i can´t update its values.

**Example:**

before (the rows are draggable):

```
Sequence  | Name

    1       Jack
    2       Angel
```

after ( i need to update the values of Sequence wherea i change their position after dropping a specific draggable row, in this case i dragged Jack at the first position and dropped it at the second position) :

```
Sequence  | Name

   1        Angel
   2        Jack
```

React/Redux it´s allowing me to change the index order of this array of elements, without getting the 'A state mutation was detected between dispatches' error message,  but is not allowing me to update the Sequence values with a new order values.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
    // within the parent class component 
    // item is an array of objects from child
    UpdateSequence(startIndex, endIndex, item) {

    // the state.Data is already an array of object
    const result = this.state.Data;
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);

    // this is working without the mutation state error
    this.setState({ Data: result })

    let positionDiff = 0;
    let direction = null;
    let newIndex = 0;

    positionDiff = endIndex - startIndex;
    if (startIndex > endIndex) {
        direction = "up";
    }
    else if (startIndex < endIndex) {
        direction = "down";
    }

    if (positionDiff !== 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x <= Math.abs(positionDiff); x++) {

            if (x === 0) {
                newIndex = startIndex + positionDiff - x;
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    Data: {
                        ...prevState.Data,
                       [prevState.Data[newIndex].Sequence]: Data[newIndex].Sequence + positionDiff
                    },
                }));
            }
      else {
                if (direction === "down") {
                    newIndex = startIndex + positionDiff - x;
                    this.setState(prevState => ({
                        Data: {
                            ...prevState.Data,
                            [prevState.Data[newIndex].Sequence]: Data[newIndex].Sequence - 1
                        },
                    }));
                }
                else if (direction === "up") {
                    Data= startIndex + positionDiff + x;
                    this.setState(prevState => ({
                        Data: {
                            ...prevState.Data,
                            [prevState.Data[newIndex].Sequence]: Data[newIndex].Sequence + 1
                        },
                    }));
                }
            }
    }
        // so when i call save action i am stepping into the 'A state mutation was detected between dispatches' error message. 
        this.props.actions.saveSequence(this.state.Data)
        .then(() => {
            this.props.actions.loadData();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            toastr['error'](error, 'error....');
        })
}
```

Calling the action 'saveSequence'  whenever i try to update the element of the array, 'Sequence', i am getting the 'A state mutation was detected between dispatches' error message.

Any help will be greatfull! Thank you!

note: The logic applied to reorder the Sequence is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i figured it out changing this part of code:

```
    //code....  

    const result = item;
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);

    // i created a new empty copy of the const 'removed', called 'copy' and update the Sequence property of the array like this below. (this code with the sequence number is just a sample of what i came up to fix it )

    let copy;
    copy = {
        ...removed,
        Sequence: 1000,
    };              

    result.splice(endIndex, 0, copy);
```

After i didn´t setState for it, so i commented this line:

```
    // this.setState({ Data: result })

    //...code
```

and the end of it was putting the result to the save action as a parameter , and not the state.

```
     this.props.actions.saveSequence(result)
```

Works and now i have i fully drag and drop functionality saving the new order sequence into the database with no more 'A state mutation was detected between dispatches' error message!

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know redux particularly well, I am noticing that you are directly modifying `state`, which seems like a likely culprit.

```
const result = this.state.Data;
const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
```

`splice` is a destructive method that modifies its input, and its input is a reference to something in `this.state`.

To demonstrate:

```
> state = {Data: [1,2,3]}
{ Data: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
> result = state.Data.splice(0,1)
[ 1 ]
> state
{ Data: [ 2, 3 ] }
```

Notice that `state` has been modified. This might be what Redux is detecting, and a general React no-no.

To avoid modifying state, the easy way out is to clone the data you are looking to modify

```
const result = this.state.Data.slice()
```

Note that this does a *shallow* copy, so if `Data` has non-primitive values, you have to watch out for doing destructive edits on those values too. (Look up deep vs shallow copy if you want to find out more.) However, since you are only reordering things, I believe you're safe.

Comment: I'd update your comment with that info since others may gravitate to the same issue. (Notice I'm suggesting the use of `slice`, not `splice`)